# Slow postgresql queries in Zend

Tags: php, postgresql, zend-framework

I am using `Zend 1.12` with `postgresql` database.
I am also using `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract` interface for accessing my database.

My code (simplified):

```
class Application_Model_DbTable_Images extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'images';

    public function getImage($id)
    {
        $row = $this->fetchRow("id = $id");
        return $row;
    }
}
```

Then I use it like this:

```
$db = new Application_Model_DbTable_Images();
$img = $db->getImage(10);
```

The thing is that this call takes just too long. In my pgAdmin this query takes something like 10-20ms but in PHP this query takes 300-500ms. I used XDebug, followed call stack and I learned that the function that takes the most of this time (over 90%) is `php::PDO->__construct`. What can I do to decrease my query duration?

Comment: Use profiler to check which exact queries are called here. My wild guess is that Zend_Db prepends each real query with `DESCRIBE table` one, and that one alone could take about 500 ms.

Comment: I'll list what is being called with its execution time in parentheses: Application_Model_DbTable_Images->getImage, Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->select(407ms), Zend_Db_Table_Select->__construct(402ms), Zend_Db_Table_Select->setTable(402ms), Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->info(402ms), Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->_setupPrimaryKey(402ms), Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->_setupMetadata(401ms), Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Pgsql->describeTable(400ms), Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->quote(389ms), Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Pgsql->connect(388ms), Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect(388ms), php::Pdo->__construct(388ms)

Comment: Well there is a 'describeTable' call. How can I make it faster?

Comment: @raina77ow I learned that I need to call this: Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultMetadataCache somewhere in my code, but where and how?

Comment: Check [this page](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.table.html#zend.db.table.metadata.caching), it describes several possible solutions to prevent those `DESCRIBE` queries. If you choose caching, I suppose all required steps should be placed in `Bootstrap` file - like shown in [this discussion](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Bootstrapping-and-setting-default-metadata-cache-on-Zend-Db-Table-td1396431.html).

Comment: Should I make this an answer for you to accept? )

Comment: @raina77ow of course you should this is how it works here.