# Slow Postgres queries in Zend

Tags: php, performance, zend-framework, postgresql

Recently I asked if there is some way of making my queries execute faster (topic: [Slow postgresql queries in Zend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474751/slow-postgresql-queries-in-zend)). I got rid off 'describe' queries which resulted in a 20-30% boost. But still my queries are too slow.

```
class Application_Model_DbTable_Images extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'images';

    public function getImage($id)
    {
        $row = $this->fetchRow("id = $id");
        return $row;
    }
}
```

I profiled my application and noticed that single getImage() call lasts about 300ms. But if I call it twice then the second call lasts roughly 15ms. What can I do to make all queries execute that fast?

I am also 100% sure that there are no describe queries anymore - I checked database queries log, all queries seem perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was enabling persistent connections with my database.
An explanation on how to do that is available [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.closing).

I am not sure if it's safe or efficient but now my queries execute under 20ms instead of hundreds of milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it's just caching. The first time it has to read the information from disk, the second time it's already in RAM.

Is 300ms plausible for fetching the row - what do you get through psql?

If you want to understand the performance of your database you'll need to have at least a basic grasp of:

1. What hardware you are running on, particularly disk I/O and seek times
2. Your query plans (via [EXPLAIN](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/using-explain.html))
3. How much data is being moved about in queries
4. Know if your database is becoming bloated ([autovaccum](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/routine-vacuuming.html) should prevent this if configured appropriately)

Comment: No - the server will be caching the disk contents, so when it tries to read that part of the disk again it's already in RAM.

Comment: 1. those cache files are just about 5kB each - file_get_contents() deals with them in no time (~1ms).  
2. there is less than 2kB of data in a single row.  
4. 'images' table contains ~3000 rows.  

I executed queries created by zend in pgadmin and they took each ~15ms. Maybe a new connection is initialized each time my controller fires up. How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

As much as the database itself can influence performance, so can the calling code. You may want to compare different ways of building the query in ZF and see if there is any difference.

current:

```
class Application_Model_DbTable_Images extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'images';

    public function getImage($id)
    {
        $row = $this->fetchRow("id = $id");
        return $row;
    }
}
```

Try:

```
class Application_Model_DbTable_Images extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'images';

    public function getImage($id)
    {
        $select = $this->select()->where('id = ?', $id);//try using the select(), ZF will anyway
        $row = $this->fetchRow($select);
        return $row;
    }
}
```

or:

class Application_Model_DbTable_Images extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'images';

```
public function getImage($id)
{
    $select = $this->select()->where('id = ?', $id);
    $row = $this->fetchAll($select);//maybe a different fetch will have an effect
    return $row;
}
```

}

Here a couple of examples of different ways to build the query (there are many more), they may or may not help your performance.